# How to pattern match on an empty nested list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a simple function that would "rotate" a matrix as a learning exercise but cannot pass the point where I have to deal with an empty nested list in the pattern matching case.

```
rotate :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
rotate m acc =
  case m of
    [] -> []
    [[]:_] -> acc
    m -> rotate (map tail m) (acc ++ [(map head m)])
```

Input: [[8, 9, 4], [7, 6, 5]]

Output: [[4,5], [9,6], [8,7]]

```
Main.hs:10:6: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the pattern: []
      In the pattern: [] : _
      In the pattern: [[] : _]    | 10 |     [[]:_] -> acc    |      ^^ Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: Just the same way `[]`. This is an empty nested list. A list with one element that is an empty list is `[[]]`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `([]:_)` (a list whose first element is an empty list) instead of `[[]:_]` (a list with a single element that is a list whose first element is an empty list)?

Comment: This is the exact case I would like to match on: Prelude> matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
Prelude> map tail (map tail (map tail (tail matrix)))
[[],[]]

Comment: @DanielWagner I think so! Let me try.

Comment: That is it thanks!

Comment: Can't tell what `acc` does but you may try `transpose . reverse` for cw and `reverse . transpose` for ccw rotation.

Comment: I am used to iterative recursion, in avoidance to blow up the stack. This might be not to do things in Haskell. Acc is the accumulator that accumulates your return value. You are right transpose is nicer.

Comment: @Istvsn, tail recursion when you are returning a list or similar data structure is often *worse* than direct (co)recursion in lazy FP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have to use the syntax suggested by @DanielWagner

```
rotate :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
rotate m acc =
  case m of
    [] -> []
    ([]:_) -> reverse acc
    x -> rotate (map tail x) (acc ++ [(map head x)])
```

Update1:

Based on @chi's suggestion:

```
transpose :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
transpose m =
  case m of 
    []      -> []
    ([]:_)  -> []
    x       -> (map head x) : transpose (map (drop 1) x)
```

Comment: `tail` is dangerous: it must be applied only to non-empty lists or it will crash. So, your code will crash when called as `rotate [[1],[]] acc` since your `case` only checks if the first list is empty (it is not being `[1]`), but not the second one (which is `[]`). If you want `tail []` to return `[]` instead of crashing, use `drop 1` instead -- it's the same as `tail`, but `drop 1 []` is `[]` instead of an error.